# Word wrap issues with SSIS Flat file destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis, notepad++, word-wrap

**Background:** I need to generate a text file with 5 records each of 1565 character length.  This text file is further used to feed the data to a software.
Hence, they are some required fields and optional fields. I created a query with all the fields added together to get one single field. I populated optional fields with a blank.

**For example:** 
Here is the sample input layout for each fields

```
Field       CharLength    Required
ID             7             Yes
Name           15            Yes 
Address        15            No 
DOB            10            Yes 
Age            1             No 
Information    200           No
IDNumber       13            Yes
```

and then i generated a query  for each unique ID with the above fields into a single row which looks like following:

```
> SELECT Cast(1 AS CHAR(7))+CAST('XYZ' AS CHAR(15))+CAST('' AS CHAR(15))+CAST('22/12/2014' AS  
  CHAR(10))+CAST('' AS CHAR(1))+CAST(' AS CHAR(200))+CAST('123456' AS CHAR(13))                                                            
  UNION                                                                                          
  SELECT Cast(2 AS CHAR(7))+CAST('XYZ' AS CHAR(15))+CAST('' AS CHAR(15))+CAST('22/12/2014' AS  
  CHAR(10))+CAST('' AS CHAR(1))+CAST(''AS CHAR(200))+CAST('123456' AS CHAR(13))
```

Then, I created an SSIS package to produce the output text file through Flat file destination **delimited**.

**Problem:**

Even though the flat file is generated as per the desired length(1565). The text file looks differently when the **word wrap** is **ON** or **OFF**. When Word wrap is off , i get the record in single line. If the Word wrap is on, the line is broken into multiple. the length of the record in either case is same.

Even i tried to use  **VARCHAR + Space** in the query instead of **CHAR** for each field, but there is no success. Its breaking the line for blank fields.

**For example:** `Cast('' as varchar(1)) + Space(200-len(Cast('' as varchar(1))))` for Information field

Question: How do make it into a single line even though the word wrap is ON.

Since its my first post, please excuse me for format of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of word wrap is to put characters on the next line in instances of overflow rather than creating an extremely horizontal scrolling document.

> Word wrap is the additional feature of most text editors, word processors, and web browsers, of breaking lines between words rather than within words, when possible.

Because this is what word wrap **is** there's nothing you can do to change its behavior.  What does it matter anyway?  The document should still be parsed as you would expect.  Just don't turn word wrap on.

As far as I'm aware, having word wrap on or off has no impact on the document itself, it's simply a presentation option.

Applications parsing a document parse it as if word wrap were off.  Something that *could* throw off parsing is breaks for a new line, but that is a completely different thing from word wrap.

Comment: Since we need to send this text file to different company, my high authorities are scared if the file gets rejected due to this problem.

Comment: if the file is being parsed by a machine and not a person, there will be no issue.  Machine's don't turn word wrap on... yet... mwuahahaha

Comment: No but seriously, if the file is to be used in an automated parsing process, there will be no issue.  Word wrap was created as a presentation convenience, and is would not be used in a traditional file import process.